# Vastu Shanti and Satyanarayana Puja

Tags: puja, vastu-shastra, satyanarayana

We have been told by Pandit that according to the book Vastu Puja and Satyanarayana Puja are not to be done on a single day.
Can perform Vastu Puja and Satyanarayana Puja in same day?